# como puedo validar un cruce de horas en jsf hibernate mysql

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, primefaces, jpa

este es mi managed bean

```
public class PeliculaMB{

public EntityManager em;
private Pelicula pelicula= new Pelicula();
private Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
private List<Pelicula> peliculas = new ArrayList<Pelicula>();
private List<Categoria> categorias = new ArrayList<Categoria>();

public String regseries() {
    pelicula = new Pelicula();
    return "registro_series";
}
private void guardarpelicula(){
    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    em.persist(pelicula);
    tx.commit();
}
public String guardarpel(){
    guardarpelicula();
    pelicula = new Pelicula();
    FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("Se guardo la serie corectamente", "insertado correctamente");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, fm);
    return null;
}


private void guardarcategoria(){
    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    em.merge(categoria);
    tx.commit();
}
public String guardar() {
    guardarcategoria();
    categoria = new Categoria();
    // se crea el objeto FacesMessage para guardar el mensaje
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Se guardó correctamente",
            "El registro se guardó satisfactoriamente ");
    // colocamos el mensaje en el contexto de Faces
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    return null;
}

public Categoria getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}
public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}
public List<Categoria> getCategorias() {
    em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    categorias = em.createQuery("from Categoria", Categoria.class).getResultList();
    return categorias;
}
public void setCategorias(List<Categoria> categorias) {
    this.categorias = categorias;
}
public Pelicula getPelicula() {
    return pelicula;
}
public void setPelicula(Pelicula pelicula) {
    this.pelicula = pelicula;
}
public List<Pelicula> getPeliculas() {
     em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    return peliculas;
}
public void setPeliculas(List<Pelicula> peliculas) {
    this.peliculas = peliculas;
}
```

esta es mi pagina jsf registrar serie

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <h:messages globalOnly="true"  showDetail="true" showSummary="false"></h:messages>
                <h:panelGrid>
                <h:outputText value="Titulo: "></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="titulo" value="#{peliculaMB.pelicula.titulo}" maxlength="20" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Debe llenar este campo"></h:inputText>
                <h:message for="titulo" ></h:message> 

                <h:outputText value="Hora Inicio"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="horain" value="#{peliculaMB.pelicula.horain}" >
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm" type="time"></f:convertDateTime>
                </h:inputText>

                <h:outputText value="Hora Fin"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="horafin" value="#{peliculaMB.pelicula.horafin}" >
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm" type="time"></f:convertDateTime>
                </h:inputText>

                <h:outputText value="Cobertura"></h:outputText>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="cobertura" value="#{peliculaMB.pelicula.cobertura}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="APT-14" itemValue="A1" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="APT-18" itemValue="A2" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="APT-T" itemValue="T"></f:selectItem>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputText value="Categoria"></h:outputText>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="cat" value="#{peliculaMB.categoria.cat}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{peliculaMB.categorias}" var="categ" itemValue="#{categ.id}" itemLabel="#{categ.cat}" ></f:selectItems>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{peliculaMB.guardarpel}" />

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

en si la clase deberia llamarse series, pero por el apuro no lei bien el titulo del ejercicio y le puse pelicula
lo que necesito es validar que al insertar una una nueva serie(pelicula) los horarios no se crucen, por ejemplo: los simpson a de 13:00 a 14:00 y no puede registrarse otra serie que este en ese rango de horas, ademas tambien me salio un error al momento de insertar una hora
es el siguiente

```
 INFORMACIÓN: ADVERTENCIA: FacesMessage(s) se han puesto en la cola, pero es posible que no se muestren. sourceId=j_idt6:horafin[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(j_idt6:horafin: '10.20' no se ha podido reconocer como fecha.), detail=(j_idt6:horafin: '10.20' no se ha podido reconocer como fecha. Ejemplo: 20:07)]oct 11, 2016 3:07:24 PM com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils renderUnhandledMessages INFORMACIÓN: ADVERTENCIA: FacesMessage(s) se han puesto en la cola, pero es posible que no se muestren. sourceId=j_idt6:horafin[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(j_idt6:horafin: '10.20' no se ha podido reconocer como fecha.), detail=(j_idt6:horafin: '10.20' no se ha podido reconocer como fecha. Ejemplo: 20:07 )] oct 11, 2016 3:08:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
```

que deberia hacer para poder insertar sin error y validar el cruce de horarios

Actualizacion: esta es mi clase

```
ackage
Import java.util.Date;
Import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
Import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
Import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
Import javax.persistence.Temporal;
Import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_pelicula")
Public class Pelicula {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
@Column(name="titulo", length=20)
private String titulo;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horain;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horafin;
private String cobertura;
private String categoria;
@ManyToOne
private Categoria cat = new Categoria(); 
public Categoria getCat() {
    return cat;
}
public void setCat(Categoria cat) {
    this.cat = cat;
}
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}
public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}
public Date getHorain() {
    return horain;
}
public void setHorain(Date horain) {
    this.horain = horain;
}
public Date getHorafin() {
    return horafin;
}
public void setHorafin(Date horafin) {
    this.horafin = horafin;
}
public String getCobertura() {
    return cobertura;
}
public void setCobertura(String cobertura) {
    this.cobertura = cobertura;
}
public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}
public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De tu JSF infiero que la clase `Pelicula` tiene atributos `horain` y `horafin`. Digamos que `pelicula` es el objeto que quieres registrar. Lo que deberías hacer es un query sobre las entidades `Pelicula` que cumplan alguna de estas dos condiciones:

1. Su `horain` es anterior o igual a `pelicula.horain` y su `horafin` es posterior o igual a `pelicula.horain` (empieza antes que tu película / serie pero termina después de que inicia y por lo tanto se superpone)
2. Su `horain` es anterior o igual a `pelicula.horafin` y su `horafin` es posterior o igual a `pelicula.horafin`

Esto cubre los cuatro casos de superposición:

```
----------------(///////////////////)------------ Pelicula que quieres registrar
-----------(//////////)-------------------------- Caso A
--------------------------------(///////)-------- Caso B
-----------(//////////////////////////////)------ Caso C
----------------------(///////)------------------ Caso D
```

Puedes hacer un query con una cláusula `where` como sigue (con las adaptaciones necesarias para tu código):

```
em.createQuery("select p from Pelicula p where (p.horain <= :horain AND p.horafin >= :horain) OR (p.horafin <= :horain AND p.horafin >= :horafin)", Pelicula.class)
    .setParameter("horain", pelicula.getHorain())
    .setParameter("horafin", pelicula.getHorafin())
    .getResultList();
```

Si la lista resultante está vacía, no hay objetos ya persistidos que se superpongan en horario con el que quieres insertar y es seguro hacer el `persist()`

Comment: Si, si me entendiste, pero ahora me sigue saliendo error al momento de insertar hora en el mysql, hay alfun

Comment: Alguna manera de insertar los campos de hora, ya que a estos les puse

Comment: @temporal(temporaltype.time)

Comment: Es difícil saber sin ver el código de tu clase Pelicula. Prueba usar un atributo de tipo java.sql.Time en lugar de Date